# Connect disparate data sources with TopBraid Composer

Tags: sparql, topbraid-composer

I'm working on a proof of concept to explore how to connect SPARQL data from different data sources.  I have two OWL classes, each from its own data model, representing information that I've extracted from two different systems.  The data models look like:

```
Order: id, itemName, quantity
Item: id, name, unitPrice
```

What I would like to do is connect these two types together using the Order.itemName and Item.name fields, and create a new field on the Order class to store the total price for the order (order.quantity * item.unitPrice).

This would be pretty trivial to do with SPARQL, but we're looking at TopBraid Composer due to its graphical mapping capabilities.  From my understanding, using a SPINMap we should be able to easily - and graphically - define the above property, but I'm having some problems getting things connected together.

I've been following the tutorial in the TBC Help under "Application Development Tools/SPIN/Ontology Mapping with SPINMap", but I'm having problems just trying to get a simple attribute mapped over.  Based on that help document, on the Diagram tab I'm drawing a line from the Item Class to the Order class and selecting the changeNamespace function with an appropriate value.  I then drew a line from the Item class to a new property on the Order class, totalPrice, and set the function to equals, just to see if I can get the property to show up.  After running the inferences, I run a SPARQL query, and the totalPrice field is empty for all of my Order classes.  I know this description was confusing - any idea what I should be doing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Matt, in your second step are you using a property from the Item class to map to the Order class?  That should work without any problems for the 'equals' template.

Check the Inferences tab in the middle-bottom row of tabs aster running inferences.  This will show all materialized inferences and can be used to verift hat your SPINMap is doing what is desired.

Also look at Configure Inferencing to make sure the TopSPIN reasoner is chosen.